# How to render only given block using Jinja2 with Flask and Pjax

Tags: jquery, python, flask, jinja2, pjax

I'm looking for a convenient way to render partial templates using Flask and [Pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax). I came up with something like this:

```py
# utils.py
def render_pjax(base, view, **kwargs):
    is_pijax = "X-PJAX" in flask.request.headers
    return flask.render_template(
        'pjax_wrapper.html', is_pjax=is_pijax, extends=base, view=view, **kwargs)

# pjax_wrapper.html
{% if not is_pjax %}

    {% extends extends %}
    {% block pjax_content %}
        {% include view %}
    {% endblock %}

{% else %}

    {% include view %}

{% endif %}
```

This way I can define templates like this:

```py
# without_pjax.html
<div>
    <h1>Search</h1>
    (...some static content..)
    <div class="content" id="search-results">
        {% block pjax_content %}

        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>

# with_pjax.html
<ul>
    <li>entry1</li>
    <li>entry2</li>
    ...
    <li>entry2</li>
</ul>
```

And use it all like this:

```py
# usage
@app.route('/')
def pjax_view():
    return render_pjax('without_pjax.html', 'with_pjax.html', context=...)
```

My solution is quite convenient, there are no place where code is duplicated, but still I have to use two templates for each pjax-compatible view. I was trying to find better way, preferably same as in this library for Django: [DjPj](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/DjPj/0.3.2). It allows to specify which block we want to render as response to pjax reqest. I tried to do the same in Flask but without success.

I would really appreciate some help with this problem. Can you mimic behaviour of DjPj in Flask + Jinja2, or maybe there are other pretty solutions that I just can't find?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, finally i created this function

```
def pjax(template, pjax_block='pjax_content', **kwargs):
    if "X-PJAX" in flask.request.headers:
        app = flask.current_app
        app.update_template_context(kwargs)
        template = app.jinja_env.get_template(template)
        block = template.blocks[pjax_block]
        context = template.new_context(kwargs)
        return u''.join(block(context))
    else:
        return flask.render_template(template, **kwargs)
```

It renders only given block from a template if pjax header are present, otherwise renders whole template. Hope it helps.